# Why size of 'BigInteger' differs when saved from what 'bitLength' reports?

Tags: java, biginteger

I have a variable named `out` that is a `BigInteger`. 
When trying to get the length of this variable in *bits* using

```
out.bitLength();
```

I receive **46**.

If I save this in file using

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("./testBig.dat"));
oos.writeObject(out);
oos.close();
```

I get a file that is **208 bytes**.

Can someone explain to me why those two values differ?

Comment: One is the number of bits representing the value of the variable, the other is the size of a file that contains a serialized value of the variable itself (which is a class) - basically all the stuff needed to recreate a live copy of the variable that got serialized. They are almost totally unrelated. Do you just want to write the value of the variable into a file?

Comment: Have you even looked at the contents of the file?

Comment: These two numbers are only tangentially related.

Comment: @fvu Yes basically that was my intention, to write all the bits that represent the number that the BigInteger holds into a file.

Comment: Have a look at the [toByteArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray%28%29) method then. It will give you an array of bytes containing the BigInteger's value in 2's complement representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) stores objects in Java's [serialization format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html); it does not just store the raw content of the `BigInteger` object.

You can only read the content back by deserializing it, for example with an `ObjectInputStream`.